# Outputting each array in a ul

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So I have a program that gets data about all the teams that are stored in a database. When I get the data I store the info inside an array. The data is the `leader_id` and the `student_id`'s. So what I'm trying to do is to output each array inside a separate `ul`.

**Teams Database**

```
id      | leader_id | student_id
1       | 123       | 0987
2       | 123       | 1234345
3       | 97678     | 56766
4       | 97678     | 67558
```

So each `leader_id` can have 1 or more `student_id`.

Also, If a `student_id` has the same `leader_id`, its in the same team as all the other `student_id`'s that have the same `leader_id`

**What I Am Trying To Do**

```
<ul>

     <li>123</li>
     <li>0987</li>
     <li>1234345</li>         

</ul>

<ul>

     <li>97678</li>
     <li>56766</li>
     <li>67558</li>    

</ul>
```

**What I'm Currently Getting**

```
<ul>

     <li>123</li>
     <li>0987</li>
     <li>1234345</li>
     <li>97678</li>
     <li>56766</li>
     <li>67558</li>

</ul>
```

**What I've Tried**

I've tried doing this (putting the loop inside the `ul`) :

```
<ul>

    <?php 

        foreach ($students_arr as $student) {
            echo "
                <li>$student</li>
            ";
        }

     ?>

 </ul>
```

That outputted this (only one of the teams):

```
<ul>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>0987</li>
    <li>1234345</li>         
</ul>
```

**My PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        ul {
            padding: 20px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        li {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 10px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <ul>

        <?php 

            // GET TEAMS

            // turn error reporting off
            error_reporting(0);

            // get connect.php file
            require '../connect.php';

            // get all team data
            $team_data = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT leader_id, GROUP_CONCAT(student_id SEPARATOR ', ')
                AS students_id FROM teams GROUP BY leader_id;");

            // check to see if query works
            if($team_data) {

                while($team = mysqli_fetch_array($team_data)) {

                    // output the teams data
                    $leader_id = $team['leader_id'];
                    $students_id = $team['students_id'];

                    $students_arr = explode(", ",$students_id);
                    $leader_first = array_unshift($students_arr, $leader_id);

                    foreach ($students_arr as $student) {
                        echo "
                            <li>$student</li>
                        ";
                    }
            }

            } else {

                header("Location: ../../admin.php?message=Sorry we could not get the data");

            }

         ?>

    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: take the `<ul>` inside the `while` then `foreach` the `$students_arr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

// GET TEAMS

// turn error reporting off
error_reporting(0);

// get connect.php file
require '../connect.php';

// get all team data
$team_data = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT leader_id, student_id FROM teams order by leader_id, student_id;");

// check to see if query works
if(!$team_data) {
    header("Location: ../../admin.php?message=Sorry we could not get the data");
}

// build an associative array of data, keep your data rendering and sql separate
$data = [];

while($team = mysqli_fetch_array($team_data)) {
    $leader_id = $team['leader_id'];
    $student_id = $team['student_id'];
    $data[$leader_id][] = $student_id;
}


// no sql beyond here
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        ul {
            padding: 20px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        li {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 10px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php foreach ($data as $leader_id => $students): ?>
<ul>
    <li><strong><?php echo $leader_id; ?></strong></li>
    <?php foreach ($students as $student_id): ?>
        <li><?php echo $student_id; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</body>
</html>
```